# Nuxt or Laravel does not get visitor's public ip

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nginx, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

There is basic setup of Nuxt + Laravel (Apiato). For nuxt I'm using reverse proxy with nginx, and for Laravel is nginx also.

When I hit endpoint from Postman I get my public IP, but when it comes to Nuxt on live site, IP is 127.0.0.1.

I used `request()->ip()` to get the IP.

I already tried to add proxy_set_header but, either I did it wrong, or it isn't applied at all.

Both apps are using the same server.

Nuxt

```
server {
    index index.html;
    server_name example.com

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-User-Agent $http_user_agent;
        proxy_set_header X-Referer $http_referer;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

Laravel

```
server {
    index index.html;
    server_name api.example.com;
    root /var/www/api.example.com/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME 
        $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fixes timeouts
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/letsencrypt/;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/api_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/api_access.log;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you there is a proxy:

```
const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'].split(',').pop() ||
  req.connection.remoteAddress
```

else do following:

```
const ip = req.connection.remoteAddress
```